# Opencart: Customer can access another customer's data

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I have 3 Groups in my OpenCart Admin, as follows:

1. **Owner**
2. **Seller**
3. **Guest**

My question is: How can I access group id 2 and 3 customers **order information** from group id 1 customer account?

I mean **owner** (an admin) should be able to check seller and guest order history. How can I allow the owner to access other customer's data? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in OpenCart. You're saying that you want to make a User associate them to the Owner group and then by editing the URL you want to be able to call other Customer Data.. Does not work like that. OpenCart already has a fantastic Admin that you can access Customer Orders and Customer Data.. Just visit the following: `Admin -> Customers -> Customers` And this will give you the option to login to the store as that customer too